# Read all key values from app.config c#

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

Hi i have the following app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="DayTime" value="08-20" />
<add key="NightTime" value="20-08" />
<add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
<add key="GridMode" value="1"/> 
</appSettings>
```

I need to read all the keys at one shot and store it some where like `Dictionary`.

I have tried following code but give me `null` value

with exception `Cannot convert Keyvalueinternalcollection to hashtable`

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings") as Hashtable;
```

How to read all keys with their values ?

Comment: `<add key="GridMode" value="1">` should be `<add key="GridMode" value="1"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashtable version.

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable((from key in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Keys.Cast<string>()
                                 let value= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]
                                 select new { key, value }).ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value));
```

*Comment to other answers*

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is predefined 'appSettings' section, use it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not cast to `Hashtable` but to `IEnumerable` instead:

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings");

foreach (var kvp in section as IEnumerable)
{
    //TODO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
var loc=(NameValueCollection)ConfigurationSettings.GetSection("appSettings");
var dic=new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach (var element in loc.AllKeys)
{
    dic.Add(element, loc[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings")
```

should suffice.